# How to select a substring after some dots in Oracle SQL

Tags: regex, oracle, select, substring

So this is my first post ever here so I'll do my best to ask my question properly ^^

I have a few SQL queries for my DB class and I'm facing an issue with a certain SELECT query.

The thing is that I have a list of author names (e.g. : 'J.K. Rowling', 'C.Maree',...) and I must select the initials in a first column and the surname in the second column.

I first tried this approach :

```
SELECT SUBSTR(NOM,0,INSTR(NAME,'.')-1) AS INITIALS, SUBSTR(NOM,INSTR(NOM,'.')+1) AS LASTNAME
FROM AUTHOR
```

But it's only working for the author that only have a single composed name, for example  with J.K. Rowling I'll have something like :

INITIALS :
 J
     LASTNAME :
            K. Rowling

when I'm trying to have 
INITIALS :
 J K
     LASTNAME :
             Rowling

I don't know how to solve this as I've searched a lot already but couldn't find anything working like I wanted it to.

I'm looking forward for your answers !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use regexp functions as follows:

```
select 
    regexp_replace(nom, '[^.]*$', '') initials,
    regexp_substr(nom, '[^.]*$') lastname
from t
```

The first expression searches for a sequence of characters other than a dot at the end of the string, and suppresses it: this gives you the initials.

The second expression captures the same sequence of characters, which is the lastname.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=72acaeeba80162543c518c8a089a466f)**:

```
with t as (
    select 'J.K.Rowling' nom from dual
    union all select 'C.Maree' from dual
)
select 
    regexp_replace(nom, '[^.]*$', '') initials,
    regexp_substr(nom, '[^.]*$') lastname
from t
```

```
INITIALS | LASTNAME
:------- | :-------
J.K.     | Rowling 
C.       | Maree
```